# Analyze a mouse click in perfomance tab of DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to analyze what happens when I click a button in my web page. After clicking the button, a spinner element will show up.

The problem is, there is a short delay between the click and the spinner. And the delay varies. I wish to measure the time elapsed between the click and spinner appearance.

So, I'm recording the page using the `Performance` tab of DevTools.
I can see `Mouse Move` in the `Interactions` section, but I cannot find the mouse click.

[image]

There are some good questions on using the DevTools [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-devtools?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931571/freeze-screen-in-chrome-debugger-devtools-panel-for-popover-inspection?rq=1) but not quite what I need.

How can I capture the moment of the click?

Comment: A click is basically a `MouseDown` followed by a `MouseUp`. Do you have these mouse events in your log?

Comment: No, they are not in the log. That is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I got from Chrome Performance when I clicked `I'm feeling lucky` button. You can see "Mouse Down" event.
[image]

But you should know the statistics is less reliable than logging a time between the events you expect to track.

Comment: Thanks, however, I was not able to see the mouse down event and now the page I was testing is unavailable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're talking about Chrome, but Firefox has this functionality:

[image]