# Is it possible to capture a DOM snapshot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to interact with a webpage that displays an element for a couple of seconds and then hides it. It show for around 5 seconds, so it would be probably enough time to right-click on it and inspect it in chrome, but the site has custom context menues associated with the right click.

I open de devtools beforehand, but the 5 seconds are not enouhg time to traverse the DOM structure looking for this element.

Is there any way to take a snapshot of the DOM in the devtools so it freezes all elements and I can inspect them without rush?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931571/freeze-screen-in-chrome-debugger-devtools-panel-for-popover-inspection this may help

Answer (score 2):

- Save Driver.PageSource at needed moment into string variable.
- Create html file, edit it and paste that string into it
- Open it in browser