# Slow down chrome dev tool debugger reaction to my behavior

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug in chrome dev tool. My form shows some weird validation error when I type something into the input field and then quickly click somewhere outside the field. I found the browser debugger is not able to catch my last click behavior and it becomes very difficult to debug where things go wrong. Is there a way to slow down the debugger's reaction?

Comment: Use "Event listeners breakpoints" panel in the Sources tab of devtools.

Comment: See also [Freeze screen in chrome debugger / DevTools panel for popover inspection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17931571)