# Highcharts: Trigger showing tooltip programatically with selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, highcharts

I have the situation where I need to create some automatic actions with selenium on a third party website (which I assume means that I can't use the highcharts api).

When the third party website is loaded, there is no tooltip element in the html body. It seems that it is dynamically added when the cursor is hovering over the chart.

I would like to for the tooltip to be shown via java selenium. If there is a javascript way to do this please let me know and I will try to transfer it to the selenium code myself

So far I have tried via the browser console with javascript to trigger a 'mouseover' event or to add a 'hover' class to different elements inside the highcharts container but I had no luck, the tooltip is not added to the html body and therefore I cannot select it.

I believe the above issue can be reproduced with the element with `highcharts-tooltip` class is not added to the html body until the user hovers on the chart.

Comment: Have you tried `visibilityOfElement` or `presenceOfElement`?

Comment: My problem is that the tooltip element is not visible. In fact it's not even added to the DOM. My problem is that I can't find a way to trigger the condition so that the tooltip is added to the DOM.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035370/i-need-to-read-the-text-with-the-tooltip-ive-tried-a-lot-of-ways-and-i-always/69040660#69040660

Comment: @pburgr Thank you but my problem is that I cannot programmatically trigger a hover event so that the tooltip element is added in the DOM in the first place. This probably has to do with the highcharts framework and what conditions it needs to show the tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get global `Highcharts` variable and call `onMouseOver` method on a specific point.

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points[0].onMouseOver();
```

You can also dispatch `mousemove` event directly on a svg element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-point')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('mousemove', { 'bubbles': true }));
```

---

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#onMouseOver

Comment: I couldn't access the global `Highcharts` variable. However, using a `mouseover` event on the point did the trick, thank you!

Comment: I am using JEST and RTL for writing unit tests. 
I can see charts being rendered inside tests when I check below assertion it is true

`expect(container.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-point").length).toBeGreaterThan(0)`

when I trigger event on the **highcharts-point** I also see `highcharts-series-hover` also gets applied which means hover was successful but the issue is `formatter` function is not triggered from `tooltip` options for highcharts.

ppotaczek can you help what am I missing here?

Comment: @Abhijeet Kulkarni, Discussion will be continued here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/442