# How can I click an element inside canvas using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, highcharts

How can I click an element inside canvas using Selenium with Python in this particular situation?

[image]Inspecting the element shows this CSS selector:
`#highcharts-hz2pb6j-471 > svg > g.highcharts-series-group > g.highcharts-series.highcharts-series-1.highcharts-column-series.highcharts-color-1.highcharts-tracker > path.highcharts-point.highcharts-point-select.highcharts-color-1`

Yet, when trying to click it
`browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[id^='highcharts-'] > svg > g.highcharts-series-group > g.highcharts-series.highcharts-series-1.highcharts-column-series.highcharts-color-1.highcharts-tracker > path.highcharts-point.highcharts-point-select.highcharts-color-1").click()`

I get this error:
`element click intercepted: Element <path fill="#385723" d="M 1217.5 200.5 L 1259.5 200.5 A 3 3 0 0 1 1262.3284271247462 202.5 L 1262.3284271247462 202.5 A 0 0 0 0 1 1262.3284271247462 202.5 L 1262.3284271247462 202.5 A 0 0 0 0 1 1214.6715728752538 202.5 L 1214.6715728752538 202.5 A 3 3 0 0 1 1217.5 200.5 Z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" opacity="1" filter="none" class="highcharts-point highcharts-point-select highcharts-color-0"></path> is not clickable at point (1652, 810). Other element would receive the click: <path fill="#92AA7A" d="M 1214.6715728752538 202.5 L 1262.3284271247462 202.5 A 3 3 0 0 1 1262.5 203.5 L 1262.5 207.5 A 0 0 0 0 1 1262.5 207.5 L 1214.5 207.5 A 0 0 0 0 1 1214.5 207.5 L 1214.5 203.5 A 3 3 0 0 1 1214.6715728752538 202.5 Z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" opacity="1" filter="none" class="highcharts-point highcharts-point-select highcharts-color-1"></path>`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sergey, You should have access to the global `Highcharts` variable and run this JS code: `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].points[0].onMouseOver();`. Please check this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124753/highcharts-trigger-showing-tooltip-programatically-with-selenium