# How can i set vuetifty 3 v-select menu checbox left and right padding?

Tags: css, vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuetify.js, dropdown

I want to reduce the left padding of v-select menu checkbox using f12 debugger, but when i click on the menu it suddenly disappears. Then i can't see the active menu.

Here is the screen shot of select menu.

[image: v-select menu screenshot]

How can i set the checkbox right or label left padding using css ?
I use the vue 3 and vuetify 3 version.

Here is the sample application https://u5ziwy-4173.csb.app/

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` in console to pause the debugger after a set amount of time allowing you to set the UI how you want for when the debugger finally pauses.  See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454481/6225326)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To keep the menu open for debugging-**

Use the [menu-props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props) of `v-select` which passes props through to the `v-menu` component and set the [model-value](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-model-value) prop of `v-menu` to **true** which will always keep the menu open.

```
<v-select 
  multiple 
  :items="items" 
  :menu-props="{ modelValue: true }"
>
</v-select>
```

**To set the padding of the list items' label**-

You can modify the class `.v-list-item-title`.

```
.v-list-item-title {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

You can debug more as per your requirements.