# I can't find an element by XPATH in a dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, css-selectors

I can't find an element by XPATH in a dropdown list.

As the image below, I want to expand the div (number 1 in the image) to be able to copy the XPATH of an element of the dropdown list. (number 3 in the image), but whatever I try to do, the "aria-hidden" changes to "true" and the dropdown disappears, and then the div I need to expand disappears too.

Does anyone know how I can find the XPATH of the elements in this list that keeps disappearing with anything I do?

[image]

........................

Comment: The same steps you would do manually.  Have Selenium click on the item. Wait for the drop to populate, then have selenium select the item

Comment: What's the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pause JavaScript execution. Open Chrome browser Go to source TAB and then hover over the element that you want to take xpath.

Now press Press Ctrl + \ it will pause javascript execution, Now you can hover and take xpath of the element.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work, when I press Press Ctrl + \, nothing happen.

Comment: Please check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396563/how-to-pause-script-execution-in-developers-console